# How to identify objects in UFT for JQWidgets?

Tags: jquery-ui

I got a application to test. It is a web based application. I started recording the application in UFT but nothing got recorded.

One more query, are JQuery UI and JQWidgets are same?

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same. [jQWidgets](http://www.jqwidgets.com/) is not based on jQuery UI. It is based on jQuery.